# Vite ?inline import query erroring when compiling with TypeScript `tsc`

Tags: css, typescript, vite, tsconfig

Vite's functionality to [inject raw CSS](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#disabling-css-injection-into-the-page) by using `import rawCss from "./component.css?inline` works perfectly fine. However, I'm running a type-check that always fails

```
path/to/MyComponent.tsx:5:24 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './MyComponent.m.css?inline' or its corresponding type declarations.

5 import rawCss from "./MyComponent.m.css?inline";
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I have a types file with vite/client imported (I can confirm it's working on my IDE)

**vite-env.d.ts**

```
/// <reference types="vite/client" />
```

Inside the vite/client, there's this piece

```
declare module '*?inline' {
  const src: string
  export default src
}
```

In the end, I managed to do a hacky workaround with creating `MyComponent.m.css?inline` files with the following code.

```
// This file is needed to work for `pnpm type:check` to work.
export default string;
```

Obviously not ideal :(